# How can I change the font color of my fortran code in emacs?

Tags: css, emacs, fortran

I really prefer green on a black background when writing fortran in emacs, but I can't find the styles.css sheet anywhere??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Emacs does not use Cascading Style Sheets for text colorization. It has a concept of Faces:

You can change the foreground and background colors of a face with M-x set-face-foreground and M-x set-face-background.

see.[Customizing faces](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Face-Customization.html)

Answer (score 1):

So you've gotten a lot of downvotes for this question. The issue is that emacs doesn't emacs doesn't use css to style its look and feel.

In emacs there is a concept called a [`face`](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Faces.html). Every aspect of emacs is styled using faces. A face essentially defines a font. It defines the family of a font for example "Times new roman", it defines a width, it defines a height, it defines a weight (italic bold... ect), it also defines the foreground color and the background color. I would highly recommend that you read that link if you want to know more info.

You can set individual faces if you want by using [`custom-set-faces`](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Applying-Customizations.html#Applying-Customizations) or [customize](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Face-Customization.html).

Although that is one way to do it its much easier to apply a theme that somebody made that will do the dirty work for you.

You can download themes from [this website](https://emacsthemes.com/). If you need more direction or help let me know. Most importantly good luck on your foray into emacs, it might be frustrating at times but its definitely worth learning.